# Question about the distribution of the average of Dirichlet-distributed random variables

Tags: convolution, dirichlet-distribution

Suppose that each in a set of $n$ random variables $\boldsymbol{X}_1, .., \boldsymbol{X}_n$ are Dirichlet-distributed with parameters $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_i$, where $i$ is an index for the random variable. I have an intuition that the average of these random vectors are also Dirichlet-distributed with parameters $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \boldsymbol{\alpha}_i$. i.e., the element-wise average of the Dirichlet distribution parameters across all random variables $i$. Am I correct?

Comment: Try out your conjecture in the case $n=2$ to see what goes wrong.